# Unset XML element function not working

Tags: php, xml

This is what I have.

```
$filename= asql($_GET['filename']);
$fullfile = "xml/".$filename;
function delete_book_id($ids){
  $data = simplexml_load_file($fullfile);
  $data_count = count($data->item);
  for($i = 0; $i < $data_count; $i++)
  {
    //basically what you want to remove
    if(($data->item[$i]->id == $ids))
    {
      unset($data->item[$i]);
    }
  }
  file_put_contents($fullfile, $data->saveXML());
}
```

lets say `$fullfile` is `xml/name.xml` and the file exists in our folder. Where the variable is called in the function it should work right?

If I replace the variable in the function with `xml/name.xml` it will work, but using the variable causes the page to break and not reload nor will it remove the line it is supposed to `unset`. Will the function not accept variables, or am I missing something here?

I have also tried using `"xml/".$filename` in place of the variable in the function. No luck there either.

Comment: What is `var_dump($filename)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$fullfile` is defined outside of the function. It's `undefined` inside of it. Use `global $fullfile;` within function or define it there.

Comment: I KNEW THAT D: I feel like a moron now!